# Import HTML tables to multiple Excel Worksheets

Tags: html, excel, import

When I import an HTML document into Excel, if there is more than one table in the HTML document Excel puts the tables on the same worksheet one after the other.  Is there a way to tell Excel to put each table on its own worksheet?

Comment: I am having a problem which apparently you seem to have the answer. Can you tell how you converted multiple tables into excel into same worksheet. One excel table after the other. Would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using the Excel XML/HTML format (circa Office 2000, but deprecated in 2010, I believe), you won't be able to do this.

If you are using plain old HTML tables (circa Office 97 "Excel HTML Extensions" era), all versions of Excel from 97 onwards will import these fine but strictly to one worksheet.